# How to identify the edges at the "outside" of a mesh in python?

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

**In python** (ideally bmesh, and not bpy.ops) is there a way to identify the edges at the "outside" of a mesh, such as the ones selected in the cylinder shown below (image edited for clarity)?

[image]

Or at the outside of the grid below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe edges adjacent to exactly one poly? For bmesh, `len(bm_edge.link_faces) == 1`?

Comment: @Gorgious - ok gotcha. New to blender, so half of my problem is "what is this thing called". Probably more than half. Thanks though

Comment: @simone the blender manual itself is a good place for finding what things are called.  For instance, [this page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/introduction.html) introduces the names of the parts of the window system.  It even has a [glossary](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html) that's sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bmesh, edges have the property `is_boundary`, so you can use code like this to select all of the boundary edges while deselecting all of the non-boundary edges:

```
object = bpy.context.object
if object.mode != 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)

bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()

for edge in bm.edges:
    if edge.is_boundary:
        edge.select_set(True)
    else:
        edge.select_set(False)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
```